# Why is the appDelegates window property's origin always 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im making a keyboard avoiding text field, and i shift up the whole screen so that the textfield is a bit above the keyboard always. Now if the keyboard is already showing, and i tap on another textfield, it should move the screen up from its current position to the new position that will reveal the next textfield.

The problem is, whenever i read the appDelegate.window.origin, its always (0,0) after doing the animation to shift it up. so if i want to do a new animation from its current shifted position, i would need to keep track of that myself in some way. Is there a reason why the origin of the appDelegate.window is always 0? is there a different variable i should look at instead to shift up the whole screen?

**UPDATE**

so i managed to solve my problem, a snippet from my code shows if you keep track of the origin yourself, you just need to update the windows.frame right before you do your animation so that the origin is correct when the animation starts. The previous question still stands though, it seems strange that the origin is always 0,0

```
        __block CGRect frame = appDelegate.window.frame;

        //set the origin of the window to the previous shifted value
        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])){
            frame.origin.y = appDelegate.currentWindowOriginShift;
        }
        else {
            frame.origin.x = appDelegate.currentWindowOriginShift;
        }

        appDelegate.window.frame = frame; //i was missing this before

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

            if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])){
                frame.origin.y -= difference;
                appDelegate.currentWindowOriginShift = frame.origin.y;
            }
            else {
                frame.origin.x -= difference;
                appDelegate.currentWindowOriginShift = frame.origin.x;
            }
            appDelegate.window.frame = frame;
        }];
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a similar functionality to this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tpkeyboardavoid ?

Comment: i guess so, ive fiddled around with it a bit more an i managed to get it working properly now, it seemed before the animation, i would need to set the windows origin again with my own variable that keeps track of where the origin is just before the animation takes place. ive managed to make it a UIView category (mostly), which i find neater than some other subclassed thing, but even though i've solved my problem, the question does still stand though

Comment: @Fonix the `frame` property "describes the view’s location and size in its superview’s coordinate system". So we need to know what is the superview of the key window to answer your question and more importantly whether we have or should have any control over it.

Comment: i guess that makes sense then, since the appDelegates window is probably the very base view, and therefore doesnt really have a superview to have a coordinate within. kind of annoying though, it surely knows somehow that its origin isnt just 0,0 though since the view moves correctly, so wonder if there is a way of accessing that information